# Execute request for each element in CSV, not per user

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jMeter 3.2 to write some tests. I have a CSV file with test account info. Each row contains login info for a user. Each user needs to request a token that is used on later requests.

My test plan:

[image: Test plan]

The get token request retrieves a token. The login requests logs in the user and returns another token. Select customer card selects a customer and returns the final token. The code for the postprocesser is (I'm not experienced in this, so any advice is appreciated):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

// Check if our map already exists
if (props.get("map") == null) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("${department}", new String(data));
    log.info("Adding department to map. Department: ${department}. Token: " + new String(data));

    props.put("map", obj.toJSONString());

} else {

    // Retrieve the current map
    map = props.get("map");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(map);

    // Add the new department (with it's token) to the map
    jobj.put("${department}", new String(data));
    log.info("Updating map for department. Department: ${department}. Token: " + new String(data));

    props.put("map", jobj.toJSONString());
}
```

**Attempt 1:**
I'm setting up a once only controller to log in a user and retrieve the token.

Now lets say I have 10 lines in my CSV file but in my test I only want to use 3 users and loop 10 times. What happens is that 3 login requests are sent (one for each user). This works fine for the first iteration. At the 2. iteration the 3 threads will use row 4-6 which doesn't have a token and thereby fail.

**Attempt 2:**
I'm using an if controller to check whether the token has been set or not. I haven't got this working at all. I added a beanshell preprocessor to the controller where I attempt to retrieve the token. If it's null or empty I set the token variable to "". In the if controller I check for this value. But yeah. No luck yet.

**Attempt 3**
In Beanshell check if the token is created already. If not, call the test fragment that retrieves it. Unfortunately this seems not possible.

It might be worth noting that I store my tokens in a property, so that all threads can access it.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you show your test plan ?

Comment: I've added my test plan

Comment: what's data? how do you get data and expect it to be the token? also how do you call test fragment in BeanShell?

Comment: Data is apparently the response from my http request. It's not something I made up. I can't call a test fragment from Beanshell, unfortunately. It would solve my problem if I could.

Comment: did you check/print data is valid and not empty in BeanShell?

Comment: It is valid and works for the first iteration of the threads. But at the 2. iteration the thread will use the next data row which is not found in my map of tokens and then the requests will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. In essence what I tried to do is to store a token for each row in the data file.

I did this by creating a `setUp Thread Group` which is executed before other thread groups. In this I loop through the data and store a token for each. Now all other thread groups may access these as they run.